# Asymptotic expansion of an infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I am new in asymptotic analysis, so the question may be trivial.

Consider a real function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{p_{n}}$, where $p_{n}$ are some positive numbers. Can $f(x)$ have an asymptotic power series at $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$? By asymptotic power series, I mean $f(x)\sim\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}$.

Comment: I assume the series defining $f$ converges in some neighbourhood of $0$. Then this series is the asymptotic power series of $f$ as $x\to 0+$.

Comment: @Gary What if the $p_n$ are not necessarily integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is "no" under the hypothesis that $p_n$ is an increasing sequence of non-integer numbers converging to infinity, and that the formula given for $f$ has a positive radius of convergence.  Suppose also without loss of generality that $a_0 = 0$.

Suppose there is an asymptotic series as described in the question.  Suppose $N < p_0 < N+1$.  Then we would have:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x) - \sum_{n=0}^N b_n x^n}{x^{N+1}} = b_{N+1}. $$
But this limit would also be the same as
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{a_0 x^{p_0}}{x^{N+1}} = \infty,$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Does the argument hold for $x$ tends to other values as well?

Comment: $f(x)$ is analytic about points $x_0>0$, so the above argument won't work, and a genuine power series expansion will work.